# How to update the kernel for a live CD Linux image

Tags: boot, kernel, customization, live-cd

I've a customized LiveCD image based on Ubuntu. It's a small image has just the required software to get the job done. The thing is that this image doesn't have modules for newer hardware such as a new network interface card. The root file system for this image is based on "aufs", which got removed from newer kernels. So, when I upgraded the kernel, the new kernel couldn't load the roof file system because the module isn't there.

So, the question is there a way to get aufs module after upgrading the kernel by installing any package that would add the module? or is there a way to change the file system for the root file system of this liveCD image by chroot to this file system from another host system like we do to customize any image?

Comment: You'd need to rebuild your entire LiveCD with the updated kernels, etc.  There is no other way to modify the LiveCD after the fact.  However, if aufs is gone from the kernels, then it's likely no longer supported as a solution and you don't have much of a solution here.

Comment: @ThomasWard, So, I can't change the filesystem from aufs to something else like Overlay2 without rebuilding the whole liveCD, because this would take much work.